# Shared Folders in Xen Hypervisor

Tags: xen, shared-directory, hypervisor

I recently started using xen hypervisor migrating from virtualbox. My host system is Ubuntu 15.04 and guest is Windows 7. I wanted to know if there is any way where we can use shared folders similar to VirtualBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

to share files, you need a shared filesystem.  there are two main
classes of these:

- network filesystems: NFS, Samba, 9p, etc.
- clustered filesystems: GFS, OCFS2, CXFS, etc. they're designed for
  SAN systems where several hosts access the same storage box.  in VM
  case, if you create a single partition accessible from several VMs you
  get exactly the same situation, (shared block device) and need the
  same solution.

what definitely won't work is to use a 'normal' filesystem (ext3/4,
XFS, ReiserFS, FAT, HPFS, NTFS, etc) on a shared partition (just like
it won't work in a shared block device).  Since every filesystem
aggressively caches metadata to avoid rereading the disk for every
access, a VM won't be 'notified' if another one modifies a directory,
so it won't 'notice' any change.  and worse, since now the cached
metadata isn't consistent with the content of the disk, any write will
result in a heavily corrupted filesystem.

PS:

There was a project called [XenFS](https://blog.xenproject.org/2009/03/26/status-of-xenfs/) which looked promising, but never reached a stable release.